# Stop Enter key from firing button click event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, onclick

I am hoping this is easy, but I have looked and can't find a solution that will work for me. I have an aspx page with 2 user controls on it. One is a user control with a spun-up Auto Complete text box, that I want the "Enter" key to to cause a postback.

I have a button in the other control on the page that the onClick does something else. When I put text in the Auto Complete and press enter, the onClick for the button fires. Is there a way to have the enter key not cause the onClick to fire.

I have tried some javascript to disable the enter key press, but that breaks my text box enter.

What are my options.

**EDIT 1**

Here is some markup that I have

```
<uc:CompanyAC runat="server" ID="ac" />
<cc2:GenericGridView OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="HtmlDataCellPrepared"
KeyFieldName="CompanyID" ID="gridCompanies" DataSourceID="ManageCompaniesObjectDataSource" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" />
```

The CompanyAC control has a textbox with some jquery that does autocomplete WS call (no need to show that

```
<asp:TextBox ID="searchbox" runat="server" Width="400px" />
```

The GenericGridView control contains a button

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button" Text="New" AllowFocus="false" OnClick="Button_Click" />
```

So what happens is that when the Enter Key is hit when the focus is on the Textbox, the button that is in the other control fires its onclick. I do not want that to happen, but I still want the postback to happen

Comment: can you please post some of your markup so we can see what you have going on?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('input').keypress(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode==13)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you might try this:

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(e){
    // Attempt form submit (after event function exits).
    var f = $(this).parents('form');
    setTimeout(function(){f.submit();}, 1);

    // Return false to prevent form submit when enter key is pressed.
    return !((window.event) ? window.event.keyCode : e.which)==13);
});
```

Comment: But I do want the form to be submitted, just not fire the onclick

Comment: If this stops the onclick, you could set a timer to submit the form.  It's quite a hack, but would work.. Adding to example.